# Is there an app which I can check the temperature of my PCI network card?

Tags: networking, temperature, sensors, pci

I have tried Hardinfo and sensors, but they don't look to meet what I'm looking for.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64 Bits.

Comment: Why do you need to check the temperature of your network card? Your network card may not have a temperature sensor, (I know that my somewhat older PCI network adapter doesn't) but if it does, and Hardinfo isn't reading it, you might want to try Psensor. Somewhat off topic, but why are you concerned about your network card's temperature?

Comment: Most NIC cards don't have temperature sensors built in, and most that do probably won't be seen.  (Are you using Mint?  I ask based on the tag)

Comment: Yes, Thomas. I'm using Linux Mint 17.

Comment: Mint is offtopic here - asking questions about Mint here, even though Mint is based off of Ubuntu, is not permitted here, as it's not an Ubuntu-supported derivative.

Comment: But the question is not related to Mint, but to an app debian-based which works not only in Debian... So it does not make sense what you say, otherwise, nobody couldn't talk about any .deb package, since it's Debian-based. I don't think you are really interested in helping people over here, but instead, you prefer to point fingers just to look as the smartest person (regardless of being a smart person or not), or something like that. You just want REPUTATION. I dare you to show me at least ONE app which works in Ubuntu, but doesn't work in Mint.

Comment: Natos, I'm concerned about it because I use an offboard network card which is close to my power hungry video card. My onboard network card burned and my wireless adapter gets too hot whenever I use it. Both Hardinfo and Psensor don't show the temperature of my network card, by the way.

Comment: Now I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and the question obviously is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Many modern computer components contain thermal sensors, including but not limited to the CPU, hard drive, and even motherboards, although to be fair, motherboards did it first.  Display cards may or may not include them but they should as they are usually the first to die from overheating.

That said, it has never been my experience that commonplace network cards monitor their temperature, nor have I known them to overheat.  They do die however, a behavior I assume is caused by power surges over the ethernet cabling, and sometimes by poor chipset quality.

If your ethernet card appears to be flakey, it could well be the card itself.  Still more likely is that your router needs to be reset, is dying, or is of poor quality.  I see failing routers with some frequency.  Some routers with big reputations caused by heavy advertising are terribly unreliable.  D-Link and Linksys come to mind first. Most Netgear routers are bulletproof, and Ironically they often cost half as much retail, and can cost a quarter the store price if you order refurbished netgear routers online, which is something I do quite frequently for my friends.

To get back to your original question, if your goal is to monitor any temperature inside your pc, your best bet is to go in search of [a self-illuminated front panel temperature monitor](http://www.tinydeal.com/5-25-LCD-Panel-Fan-Speed-Controller-CPU-HD-Temperature-Sensor-for-PC-Computer-p-116253.html?currency=USD) and attach the wired thermistor included with the kit to whatever components inside your pc.  Many of these are configured to monitor four components such as your display card and some of them even offer outputs for variable speed cooling fans.  I probably don't have to tell you these devices are aimed primarily at overclockers obsessed with gaming, but they can just as well be applied to sensible people concerned to reliability and system longevity.

I apologize if I seem to issue TMI, but I beg of you to please understand I do not do this to brag, but rather to give you all information which will help ensure your success.

Comment: Thank you for all that information. If they don't usually overheat (even though it's an offboard card close to a Geforce 9600?), I don't think I need to worry. I also don't know if I can really monitor the network temperature (PCI card) with that item, by the way.

Comment: @AcácioFlorentino, other things can cause computers to appear unstable, including a power supply which is full of dust or just old or of poor quality.  Even good quality clean power supplies can become unstable if the computer becomes upgraded with hardware that draws too much current.

Comment: Yeap, my computer was bought in ~2007. Pretty old and tough, isn't? :D

Comment: @AcácioFlorentino, Most parts of a computer can be cleaned reasonably with a toothbrush setting up a common household fan carry out the lifted dust.  The power supply is harder to clean due to its style of construction being nearly completely enclosed.  Compressed air can clean a power supply effectively but the static fields thrown up by the rushing air is enough to kill the rest of the computer so if you use compressed air of the type garages use to clean your power supply, please disconnect all leads to drives and the motherboard before trying this.

Comment: Since I wrote that reply, I found it necessary to monitor several temperatures at once and looked for software which might do that.  I settled on Psensor, see: ( https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/psensor/ ) I can find little faults with it here and there, but it has been extremely helpful designing my new computer case from scratch.

Comment: That is a great app! I'm going to use it here too.

Comment: Anecdotally I have stumbled across this Q&A because I am searching for a way to monitor network cards temperatures. We just had the case that with a new batch of servers we had several packet errors throughout the day, and upon someone checking if physically something is wrong, they found that the passively cooled cards were running very hot. We increased airflow to max, and the network errors are gone for now.